# Vector: Get closest vectors based on a single vector

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, vector, compare

**Update:**

Thanks to the user @Thomas I was able to fix my script.
You can find his comments in the comment section below.

To make it easier, here the most important quotes:

> [...] why do your vectors contain strings instead of numbers?

I accidently kept on using strings in my vectors, thus breaking proper results.
Make sure not to use any strings when working with numbers.

In addition, make sure your results are proper sorted:

> **Sort by:**
>
> min(||house.min - client||, ||house.max - client||)
>
> **or**
>
> ||(house.max + house.min)/2 - client||

---

---

**The problem:**

I have an array with 3 houses, each containing two X, Y, Z vectors. One of them is the min point, whereas the other is the max. Those two vectors represent the field/area the house is in.

In addition, I have one client which is represented by a single vector.

Now I want to get the closest houses a client is near to. Preferably based on the min and max vector of a house.

---

**Values:**

```
var houses = [
    {
        "max": { x: "-7839.9688", y: "-7469.0312", z: "215.537" },
        "name": "House 1",
        "min": { x: "-7112.0312", y: "-7932.9692", z: "72.0312" }
    }, {
        "max": { x: "-6380.0312", y: "-9586.1963", z: "372.1475" },
        "name": "House 3",
        "min": { x: "-6764.2441", y: "-9189.0312", z: "96.3953" },
    }, {
        "max": { x: "-7747.1074", y: "-8659.9023", z: "422.2812" },
        "name": "House 2",
        "min": { x: "-6827.3853", y: "-9668.9688", z: "72.0312" },
    }
]
```

> **Please note:** The array above does not represent the figure below. The figure is just for illustration purposes only. In this particular case,
>   client 1 is close to house 2. However. In a different use-case, he/she
>   might be close to house 3.

---

**Illustration / Figure:**

[image]

---

**Approach 1:**

```js
var houses = [
  {
    "max": { x: "-7839.9688", y: "-7469.0312", z: "215.537" },
    "name": "House 1",
    "min": { x: "-7112.0312", y: "-7932.9692", z: "72.0312" }
  }, 
  {
    "max": { x: "-6380.0312", y: "-9586.1963", z: "372.1475" },
    "name": "House 3",
    "min": { x: "-6764.2441", y: "-9189.0312", z: "96.3953" },
  },
  {
    "max": { x: "-7747.1074", y: "-8659.9023", z: "422.2812" },
    "name": "House 2",
    "min": { x: "-6827.3853", y: "-9668.9688", z: "72.0312" },
  }
]
    
var client = {}

client.x = '-7514.48'
client.y = '-9443.54'
client.z = '-183.969'

var distances = []

for (var i = 0; i < houses.length; i++) {
  
  var house = houses[i]
  
  var distance_between_house_min_max = Math.sqrt(((house.min.x - house.max.x)*(house.min.x - house.max.x)) + ((house.min.y - house.max.y)*(house.min.y - house.max.y)) + ((house.min.z - house.max.z)*(house.min.z - house.max.z)));
  
  // Here I would like to take house.max and house.min together in order to get the clients distance to a the house
  
  var distance_of_client_to_house = Math.sqrt(((client.x - house.max.x)*(client.x - house.max.x)) + ((client.y - house.max.y)*(client.y - house.max.y)) + ((client.z - house.max.z)*(client.z - house.max.z)));
  
  console.log("Distance to " + house.name + " is: " + distance_of_client_to_house)
  
  distances.push({ house: house, distance: distance_of_client_to_house })

}

// Order distances by lowest distance

distances = distances.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.distance > b.distance
});

console.log("Distances:")
console.log(distances)
```

---

**Approach 2:**
Since Stackoverflow do not support node JS modules, I did not include this approach in the first place. That's why I headed for approach 1 with strings instead of 'real' vector objects.

Basically, in this approach we use the [vec3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vec3) node JS module which offers vector manipulation.

```
var vector = require("vec3").Vec3

var houses = [
  {
    "max": new vector(-7839.9688, -7469.0312, 215.537),
    "name": "House 1",
    "min": new vector(-7112.0312, -7932.9692, 72.0312)
  }, 
  {
    "max": new vector(-6380.0312, -9586.1963, 372.1475),
    "name": "House 3",
    "min": new vector(-6764.2441, -9189.0312, 96.3953),
  },
  {
    "max": new vector(-7747.1074, -8659.9023, 422.2812),
    "name": "House 2",
    "min": new vector(-6827.3853, -9668.9688, 72.0312),
  }
]

var client = new vector(-7514.48, -9443.54, -183.969)

var distances = []

for (var i = 0; i < houses.length; i++) {

  var house = houses[i]

  var distance_between_house_min_max = house.min.distanceTo(house.max);

  // Here I would like to take house.max and house.min together in order to get the clients distance to a the house

  var distance_of_client_to_house = client.distanceTo(house.max);

  console.log("Distance to " + house.name + " is: " + distance_of_client_to_house)

  distances.push({ house: house, distance: distance_of_client_to_house })

}

// Order distances by lowest distance

distances = distances.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.distance > b.distance
});

console.log("Distances:")
console.log(distances)
```

**Demo:** https://tonicdev.com/stevemuster/57c3a52fee25751400967ddd

**Question:** How can I correctly guess the houses a client is near to? I am open for all your suggestions/hints. Thank you.

Comment: So to clarify, you're not having a programming or JS problem, rather, you're not sure about the maths involved in the calculation?

Comment: mathematically speaking: sort the houses ascending on `min(||house.min - client||, ||house.max - client||)`. Question, why do your vectors contain strings instead of numbers? *edit:* or on `||(house.max + house.min)/2 - client||`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @nnnnnn Well, it is actually both. I'm not sure if this is a question for stack-maths, since it contains a lot of code. So I thought Stackoverflow would be a good place.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your hint! I will now look into this. I also updated my initial post to reflect your question on strings.

Comment: Thank you very much once again! Your hint on "sorting the houses ascendig" made it, In addition, I accidently used strings in my development script, thus breaking vector functionality. Quite weird since I removed them earlier. However. I'm glad this is fully functional now. It can be improved with radius and all that stuff, to further tune the behaviour. Something I might work on later. Thanks!